# How to make lag go down in kafka stream based application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am having a real env with 3 kafka machine cluster which is receiving lot of data. For each topic there are 25 partitions with replication factor set to 2.

My application which (kafka stream based application) gets data from this kafka cluster was down for more than a month. Now, there is huge pile of lag in each partition; to the tune of 90000000.

I am aware of the following parameters:

```
max.poll.records ; default —> 500
max.partition.fetch.bytes ; default —> 1048576
fetch.max.bytes ; default —> 52428800
fetch.min.bytes ; default —> 1

max.poll.interval.ms ; default —> 300000
request.timeout.ms; default —> 30000
session.timeout.ms ; default —> 10000
```

I have 2 consumer nodes (which same group id which are consuming the data from kafka cluster).

However, it is not catching up on lag, it remains same. Can anyone suggest how it can be improved to make lag go down?

Answer (score 0):

If your application was down for a month, some records were expired, as default retention in a topic is 7 days, so in all probability, you lost some messages. Also, default offset reset has retention either 1 or 7 days depending on your Kafka Streams version. Seems you have `auto.offset.reset: earliest`, so it starts consuming messages from the beginning per each partition. If you need to skip all messages and consume only new messages, you should set `auto.offset.reset: latest` and change `application.id` value to a new one.

If you want to parallel consuming of messages and speed up a lag decrease, you could either set config `num.stream.threads` to some value like `12` (`num.stream.threads * numberOfConsumerNodes` should be less or equals than `numberOfPartitions`, otherwise, some threads will be idle), or need to increase number of consumer nodes.

Comment: I have 25 partition for each topic, and I have 25 consumers , so that I have already taken care of.  Are there any other factors which can help speed up? FYI, I have 2 machines which are running 13 clients (same consumer group, in a thread).

Comment: do you have some time-consuming operations on consumer per each record? what is approximate new messages rate per second on a single topic? I try to understand the reason why your consumer so slow. you could speed up it by increasing number of partitions twice, so theoretically you will consume twice faster.

Comment: The main thread consumer copies data locally and other thread updates to some 3rd party store. So, ideally we don't have any time consuming operation for the client thread which fetches the data from kafka.